# How get the same ViewModel,that shared between fragments via "by navGraphViewModels(R.id.main_graph)" in activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have MainActivity with

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
    ...some>
```

and I Have two fragments. In each fragment i get ViewModel object, that shared beetween fragments:

```
val viewModel: MyViewModel by navGraphViewModels(R.id.main_graph)
```

R.id.main_graph is nested navigation into main navigation, that unite two fragments.

How get the same MyViewModel object in MainActivity?

updated

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/main_graph"
    >

    <navigation android:id="@+id/main_graph"
        app:startDestination="@id/userListFragment"
        >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/userListFragment"
            android:name="com.vazheninapps.githubuserwatcher.screens.fragments.UserListFragment"
            android:label="fragment_user_list"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_list">
            <action
                android:id="@+id/action_userListFragment_to_userDetailedFragment"
                app:destination="@id/userDetailedFragment"
                app:enterAnim="@android:anim/slide_in_left"
                app:exitAnim="@anim/fade_out" />
        </fragment>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/userDetailedFragment"
            android:name="com.vazheninapps.githubuserwatcher.screens.fragments.UserDetailedFragment"
            android:label="fragment_user_detailed"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_user_detailed" />
    </navigation>
</navigation>
```

Comment: Post your navigation graphs.

Comment: how you ask, posted

Comment: So the viewmodel is scoped to the lifetime of the nested graph. If you want it to persist for the lifetime of the activity, you will obviously have to alter the method call. `by activityViewModels()` will scope it to the activity.